# How to execute a shell command and input that output inside yaml data

Tags: shell, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have a yaml file and a shell script having curl requests with below logic. I need to get the output of shell script and place it in the yaml data value.

For eg:
shell script logic:

```
servers=`curl test.com/servers` 
for a in servers; do
  val=`curl $a/number`
  if [$val == 0]
    output=`curl $a/ip`
done
echo $output
```

If value of $output is programming, then I need test.yaml:

```
name: test
config: $get_output_value_from_shell  #config: programming
```

It could be really helpful if someone helps me to solve this. I need to achieve this in helm.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell script should be able to just write the file.

```sh
output=$(curl "$a/ip")
cat >install-values.yaml <<EOF
name: test
config: $output
EOF
```

You also might consider a higher-level language to achieve this; for example, Python has `requests` and `pyyaml` libraries that can be combined to assemble a YAML file from HTTP requests, and it will be easier to get quoting and escaping correct than in a shell script.

Helm itself can neither invoke external commands nor make arbitrary HTTP requests, so you need to do this in some tool before you run `helm`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I will do helm install only one time (with replica count as 2 ) and 2 pods will be installed with one helm install command. So this leads me to have same ips in the config of both pods. But I need to have two different config to each pod. How can I achieve that in this case?

Comment: You need two different Deployments for this; every Pod created by a Deployment is identical.